# Apache Directory Server LDAP Setting

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds

In my org there is CORP network where we have LDAP server and I can connect that server very easily through java program by proving username(principal) & password. below is my java code to connect to org LDAP server.

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://corp.testorg.com:10389");      
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CORP\\username");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
try
{
 DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
 System.out.println("connected");
}
```

But my problem is that,I have created my own LDAP server through apache DS on my local machine and then trying to connect to that local LDAP server through same program then I have to provide the base dn with username like as below

```
put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=username,ou=users,o=test")
```

why I have to provide base dn with username I am not understanding. Am I missing some configuration on LDAP server  please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported formats of the SECURITY_PRINCIPAL are very much depending on the service provider.  Usually, the distinguished name of the user is expected, but [Active Directory supports a couple of additional formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx).

Comment: Okay. So the CORP is provided by the service provider. but what they have done such setting so that i can do it on my local LDAP server & I should not have to pass base DN with the username in SECURITY_PRINCIPAL